# Need help forming valid "citation" data in schema.org structure

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I'm struggling to understand how to properly format the [citation](https://schema.org/citation) property for Articles on a website. The documentation only indicates it accepts Text or CreativeWork types, but how would I add multiple? Can I make it an array?

Right now I have something like this:

```
[{
    "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https:\/\/bhamrick.com\/article-url\/"
    },
    "url": "https:\/\/bhamrick.com\/article-url\//",
    "headline": "Article Title",
    "description": "This is an excerpt from the article",
    "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https:\/\/cdn.bhamrick.com\/article-image.jpg",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 628
    },
    "datePublished": "2019-12-10T18:10:23-08:00",
    "dateModified": "2020-02-26T18:24:00+00:00",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Bryce Hamrick",
        "url": "",
        "description": "This is my bio.",
        "sameAs": ["https:\/\/bhamrick.com\/", "https:\/\/twitter.com\/https:\/\/twitter.com\/bhamrick"]
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "https:\/\/bhamrick.com\/#organization",
        "name": "Bryce Hamrick",
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "@id": "https:\/\/bhamrick.com\/#logo",
            "url": "https:\/\/cdn.bhamrick.com\/logo.png",
            "width": 600,
            "height": 60
        },
        "image": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "@id": "https:\/\/bhamrick.com\/#logo",
            "url": "https:\/\/cdn.bhamrick.com\/logo.png",
            "width": 600,
            "height": 60
        }
    },
    "articleSection": "Article Category",
    "keywords": "",
    "wordCount": 5151,
    "citation": []
}]
```

For the "citation" property, should I change it to look like this?

```
"citation: [
    {
        "@type": "CreativeWork",
        "sameAs": "https:\/\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\/pmc\/articles\/01234567\/"
    }, {
        "@type": "CreativeWork",
        "sameAs": "https:\/\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\/pmc\/articles\/567891011\/"
    }
]
```

What other data is beneficial to include for crawlers like Google?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: He's asking whether this is valid structured data (see title).  I have the same question, i.e. can 'citation' be an array (considering it's singular). Give him a break.

Answer (score 0):

If you test your code (with the `citation` array) on the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) - it will come through as valid. Making `citation` an array is acceptable there, so I'd say that's a fine way to handle it.

As far as what else you can add to each `CreativeWork`, that would depend on what each `CreativeWork` is. For that you can reference what is available at the [schema.org specification for CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork).

I'd note that while Google validates `citation` in your example, there's not much about it on [Google Structured Data Documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data). Even if it's a good structured data practice, you may not gain much SEO benefit from this - but that's a better question to bring up on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in, I'm using the 'url' property, I think that's more accurate for this purpose, although both are probably valid.

My logic is: If you haven't defined something, how can it be the 'sameAs' something else?

```
"citation: [
{
    "@type": "CreativeWork",
    "url": "https:\/\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\/pmc\/articles\/01234567\/"
}, {
    "@type": "CreativeWork",
    "url": "https:\/\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\/pmc\/articles\/567891011\/"
}
```

]